# Fixing copyfiles from folder on inf file

Tags: dll, wdk, inf

I'm trying to verify and create a catalog for an inf file. It was already done in the past, but now I'm trying to make a few improvements. Important detail is, the files on wow64 are on 32 bits version, which are important for the program also.
So, the content of the cab file is like this:

```
root folder
  |-wow64
    |-el.dll
    |-radar.dll
  |-el64.dll
  |-pe64.sys
  |-radar.dll
  |-xr.cat
  |-xr.inf
```

And the inf file related parts are the following:

```
[DestinationDirs]
DefaultDestDir=11
DriverCopyFiles=10,System32\Drivers
DllCopyFiles=11
DllCopyFilesWOW64=16425

[SourceDisksFiles]
pe64.sys=1
el64.dll=1
radar.dll=1
el.dll=2
radar.dll=2

[SourceDisksNames]
1=%INSTDISK%,,,.\.
2=%INSTDISK%,,,.\wow64\.

[DllCopyFiles]
elx64.dll,,,0x00001002
radar.dll,,,0x00001002

[DllCopyFilesWOW64]
el.dll,wow64\el.dll,,0x00001002
radar.dll,wow64\radar.dll,,0x00001002
```

To be sure of the inf file I'm using the tools from WDK, which are in my case the infverify and inf2cat executables.

What I get from the infverify on that inf file is an error 1230 on the DllCopyFilesWOW64 because the file wow64\el.dll cannot be found, as well as the wow64\radar.dll. Trying to fix this I renamed on the SourceDisksFiles both files to wow64\el.dll=1 and wow64\radar.dll=1. In this way the base folder is .\.

Trying that idea, The infverify doesn't complain, but with the inf2cat what I get is related to the el.dll file, error 22.9.1 el.dll is missing or cannot be decompressed from source media.  Please verify all path values specified in SourceDisksNames, SouceDisksFiles, and CopyFiles sections resolve to the actual location of the file, and are expressed in terms relative to the location of the inf.

What I could achieve was to change a copyfile from the inf file like this:

```
[DllCopyFilesWOW64]
el.dll,,,0x00001002
radar.dll,,,0x00001002
```

In this way is working, but the radar.dll which is copied on the wow64 folder on the computer is the false one, it means, the 64 bits file version instead of the 32 bits one.

I appreciate any help on this.